# Script bash delete older files on directories with special chracters

Tags: bash, find

I use a script for delete older files on Trash or directories type Junk, or similar.

It works fine except when it has special characters or spaces in the names

```
/home/theos98/mail/theos98.es/dmalmierca/.Trash.Renfe Mart&AO0-n Fernandez
/home/theos98/mail/theos98.es/dmalmierca/.Trash.Renfe Cordoba
/home/theos98/mail/theos98.es/dmalmierca/.Trash.Renfe - Sevilla
```

In this scenario not work

I use two formats but not work

```
for p in $(cat /tmp/listado.txt); do  find "$p" -type f -mtime +50 -delete; done
```

or

```
for p in $(cat /tmp/listado.txt); do  find $p -type f -mtime +50 -delete; done
```

And two get this error

```
 /home/theos98/mail/theos98.es/dmalmierca/.Trash.Renfe Not found
```

I dont' know how can pass to script correct line.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` statement "reads" input word by word. You need to read it line by line.

```
while read -r line; do find "$line" -type f ...; done < /tmp/listado.txt
```

The `-r` prevents backslashes in the lines from being interpreted.